# Disable directory browsing of uploads folder

Tags: htaccess, security, directory

I'm using Wordpress as a CMS for a simple website.
I want to prevent users from being able to browse the directories such as the wp-content/uploads folder or any directories of my theme.

My host does not allow me to use "Options" or "DirectoryIndex" within a .htaccess file.
I have tried putting a .htaccess file in the /uploads/ folder with "IndexIgnore *" in it.
However none of my images from the /uploads/ folder will show up on my site with that option.
I also tried password protecting the directory with a .htpasswd file but this gives any visitor of my site a popup asking them to enter the credentials.

So my question is how do I prevent people from browsing the directories while enabling me to embed files from those directories in my wordpress posts/pages.

For example, can I place .htaccess file in the /uploads/ directory and add RewriteRules so WordPress can still show the files on my website?

Comment: Have you contacted the host? They not be using Apache, so they would need to do it on the nginx side.

Comment: No, but the host states in their FAQ that you cannot use "Options" or "DirectoryIndex" in the .htaccess files for security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable directory browsing all you have to do is drop in a blank `index.html` file into the `wp-content\uploads` directory, each subsequent sub-directory also would need a blank index file, [there are plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-directory-listings/) that can automatically do this for you.

ps. Get a better host, there is no reason they should disallow you having your own .htaccess files.

Comment: I can still have my own .htaccess files but they can't contain "Options" or "DirectoryIndex". I've tried the plugin mentioned which adds rewrite rules to the .htaccess file. Unfortunately that gives me another Internal Server Error: IndexIgnore is not allowed here.

Comment: Can I use IndexIgnore in the /uploads/ folder for example while adding RewriteRules so WordPress can still display my files on my website?

Comment: Then put a blank index.html file inside the directories as I suggested.

Comment: Thank you, I have done that for now.
I was hoping it would also be possible with RewriteRules in combination with IndexIgnore in the /uploads/ folder.